# ionic $ionicSlideBoxDelegate slidesCount not correct after update

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm writing a simple ionic app. My controller is quite simple so far..

```
.controller('CardsCtrl', function($scope, dataFactory, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $stateParams) {

    var parentID = $stateParams.parentID;
    var keyIDNumber = $stateParams.keyID;

    $scope.card = [];


    var httpcall = dataFactory.getPosts()
        .success(function (posts) {

            $scope.card = dataFactory.getChildPosts(parentID, posts, keyIDNumber);

            $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
            console.log($ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slidesCount());
         });

    //more stuff....
```

})

My template has an ng-repeat so I .update() on success of the data and so all my slides are there as I would expect. However, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slidesCount() is still returning 0 after the .update() - even though I have got five slides at the moment.

Even though the .update() doesn't seem to require it I've tried adding a $getByHandle but to no avail! Any ideas how I can get the slide count?

Comment: Couldn't you just do `$scope.card.length`?

Comment: yes - but really I'm trying to be able to use the next() and  slide() methods which I can't get to work either. My theory is that these won't work because the slidesCount() is still zero when it should be  value.

Answer (score 0):

I found that setting a timeout -

setTimeout(function(){console.log($ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slidesCount()),0});

solved the problem. I was then able to slide() to my required slide. 
I found a post on the ionic forum that helped:

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionicslideboxdelegate-update-then-when-done-execute-function/10483/14